# I don't know how to represent the curves in the graph below.

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

[image]

So I am making an Arcade game and I am trying to make the difficulty curve smooth (now the values are hard coded), but I don't know how f(x) or f(g(x)) should look like in order to achieve this.

I found this resource [Transforming Game Difficulty Curves usingFunction Composition](https://dl.acm.org/doi/fullHtml/10.1145/3290605.3300781#:%7E:text=The%20difficulty%20curve%20of%20a,over%20the%20course%20of%20gameplay.) , but I find it hard to understand as a whole.
I have basic knowledge about functions and calculus but I haven't used them in a while.

Any advice or resource that I can research is well received.

I would love it if any potential solution to my problem comes with some explanation. I want to understand what I am doing 100% .

Thank you for your time and atentintion.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you need? I'm not sure what you mean by $\frac{f(x)}{f(g(x))},$ I don't see any other reference to an $f$ or $g.$ If you just want the equation for the baseline curve then that's in the article, about halfway down

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thank you for your response. I meant to write f(x) or f(g(x)). I've seen the equation in the article and the composing operations required to alter the difficulty curve in the desired way. I tried to reproduce them and didn't get the same result. My question's sole purpose was to get a little bit more clarity or a "simpler/more general explanation". I'm sure my rusty math knowledge is one of the reasons why I didn't understand the explanation in the article in the first place .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical function that models this sort of behavior is a [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function):
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(x - a)/d}}
$$
where $a$ is the "center" of the function (such that $f(a) = \frac12$), and $d$ is a parameter that controls the "steepness" of the transition from small values of $f$ to large values of $f$ (smaller $d$ means a "steeper" transition.)

[Here's a Desmos calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dzcovhkife) that allows you to play around with the parameters and see what works best for your application.